# Book recommendation for maths based on a physics book

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

So basically I was reading griffiths electrodynamics and I read the part of vector analysis in it. Now that was all just for physics and not in to much detail now I would like to know which book or which lectures can I study to learn about vector analysis like vector fields,curl, divergence gradients from a maths perspective. I would want it to be of mostly begginer level as I know single variable calculus and basic vector addition and multiplication. I want it to have all the topics like Dirac delta function vector fields theory, Spherical coordinates, curl,divergence, gradient, potentials . Cheers

Comment: For my humble opinion this book is very very nice: Introduction to Electrodynamics - Griffiths https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41SmJRCkGYL._SX383_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg for your request.

Comment: @NarutoUchiha: Look at Div, Grad, Curl, and All That: An Informal Text on Vector Calculus (Fourth Edition) 4th Edition by H. M. Schey  on your favorite book site and see if satisfies your needs.